# Confused between CoffeeScript of different models - Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have 2 different functions called `calculate` on different files, one for `orders` model and other for `purchases` model.

I'm getting this error when I try to execute `calculate` on /orders/new

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: calculate is not defined       purchases.self-6858fedfd0064c08d3c05b0717b6d95c49ec42827fde8137263cd5e56e90e153.js
```

Why is talking about `purchases` error? I don't know why but rails is confusing my javascript assets.

**CODE:**

```
# purchases.coffee
$ ->
    $("#show-add-detail-form-btn").click ->
        $("#add-detail-form-btn").show()
        $("#show-add-detail-form-btn").parent().parent().hide()
    $("#hide-add-detail-btn").click ->
        $("#add-detail-form-btn").hide()
        $("#show-add-detail-form-btn").parent().parent().show()

    root = exports ? this

    # Add a row to purchase
    root.add_row = () ->
        # Set line data
        name = $('#line_name').val()
        price = $('#line_price').val()
        # Set line number
        line_tag = $("#purchase_detail #line_id_val")
        line = 1
        line_tag.each ->
            line = line + 1
        # Displays and hides
        if $("#empty_purchase_alert").is(':visible')
            $("#empty_purchase_alert").hide()
        if $("#purchase_table").hasClass('hidden')
            $("#purchase_table").removeClass('hidden')
        if $("#process_purchase").is(':hidden')
            $("#process_purchase").show()
        $("#add-detail-form-btn").hide()
        $("#show-add-detail-form-btn").parent().parent().show()
        $('#line_name').val('')
        $('#line_price').val('')
        # Append row
        $("#purchase_table #purchase_detail").append('
            <tr id="row_'+line+'">
                <td>
                    <span id="line_id_val">'+line+'</span>
                    <input class="hidden" value="'+line+'" name="purchase[purchase_detail][][line]">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="line_name_val">'+name+'</span>
                    <input class="hidden" value="'+name+'" name="purchase[purchase_detail][][name]">
                </td>
                <td>
                    Bs. <span id="line_price_val" class="price">'+price+'</span>
                    <input class="hidden" value="'+price+'" name="purchase[purchase_detail][][price]">
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <button type="button" onclick="remove_row('+line+')" id="btn_remove_'+line+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remover</span>
                  </button></td>
                </td>
            </tr>')
        calculate()

    # Remove the selected row from the purchase
    root.remove_row = (line) ->
        $('#row_'+line).remove();
        if $("tbody#purchase_detail").children().length == 0
            $("#purchase_table").hide()
            $("#process_purchase").hide()
            $("#empty_purchase_alert").show()
        calculate()

    # Calculates subtotal, tax and total
    root.calculate = () ->
        # Calculate comissions
        subtotal = 0
        $("#purchase_detail .price").each ->
            # Sum subtotal
            i = parseFloat($(this).text());
            subtotal += i
        # Calculate taxes
        iva = $("#iva").val()
        tax = subtotal * iva
        # Calculate total
        total = subtotal - tax
        # To display
        $("#subtotal").text(subtotal)
        $("#tax").text(tax)
        $("#total").text(total)
        # To send as params
        $("#purchase_subtotal").val(subtotal)
        $("#purchase_tax").val(tax)
        $("#purchase_total").val(total)

# orders.coffee
$ ->
  # Customers search
  $("#order_customer_id").change ->
    customer = $(this).find("option:selected").text()
    $("#order_customer_search").val customer

  # Products search
  $("#product_list").change ->
    customer = $(this).find("option:selected").text()
    $("#order_product_search").val customer

  $("#btn-add-product").click ->
    btn = $("#btn-add-product")
    btn.prop "type", "button"  if btn.prop("type", "submit")
    btn.prop "type", "submit"  if btn.prop("type", "button")

  # Product quantity update
  $(document).on 'change', '#product_list', (evt,data) ->
    $("#product_details_box").empty();
    $.ajax 'update_quantity',
      type: 'GET'
      url: '/orders/update_quantity'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        product_id: $("#product_list option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        $("#product_details_box").append('
            <table class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>Serial</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Fecha registro</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Comentario</th>
                  <th class="text-center"></th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="details_box">
              </tbody>
            </table>
          ')
        product = JSON.parse data
        if product.length == 0
          $("#product_details_box table").hide()
        else
          for pkey, pval of product
            price_id = pval.current_price.id
            price_val = pval.current_price.price
            for key, val of pval.product_details_availables
              comment = if !!val.comment then val.comment else "-"
              btn = if $("#row_"+val.id).is(':visible') then "hidden" else "visible"
              $("#details_box").append('
                  <tr>
                    <td>'+val.id+'</td>
                    <td>'+val.serial+'</td>
                    <td class="text-center">'+val.created_at+'</td>
                    <td class="text-center">'+comment+'</td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                      <button type="button" onclick="add_row(\''+val.product_id+'\',\''+pval.name+'\',\''+price_id+'\',\''+price_val+'\',\''+val.id+'\',\''+val.serial+'\',\''+comment+'\')" id="btn_add_'+val.id+'" class="btn btn-success btn-xs '+btn+'">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Agregar</span>
                      </button></td>
                  </tr>
                ')

  root = exports ? this

  # Add the selected serial to an order
  root.add_row = (product_id,product_name,price_id,price_val,detail_id,serial,comment) ->
    $("#btn_add_"+detail_id).hide()
    $("#order_table").removeClass("hidden")
    $("#order_table").show()
    if $("#empty_orden_alert").is(':visible')
      $("#empty_orden_alert").hide()
      $("#process_order").show()
    $("#order_table #order_detail").append('
        <tr id="row_'+detail_id+'">
          <td>
            <span>'+product_id+'</span>
            <input class="hidden" value="'+product_id+'" name="order[order_detail][][product_id]">
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>'+product_name+'</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>'+serial+'</span>
            <input class="hidden" value="'+detail_id+'" name="order[order_detail][][product_detail_id]">
          </td>
          <td>
            Bs. <a id="price_'+detail_id+'">'+price_val+'</a>
            <input class="hidden" value="'+price_id+'" name="order[order_detail][][price_id]">
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <label id="comission_'+detail_id+'" maxlenght="2" contenteditable onkeypress="return just_numbers(event)" onkeyup="calculate(\''+detail_id+'\')">0</label>%
            <input id="comission_'+detail_id+'_input" class="hidden" value="0" name="order[order_detail][][comission]">
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <span>'+comment+'</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" onclick="remove_row(\''+product_id+'\',\''+product_name+'\',\''+detail_id+'\',\''+serial+'\',\''+comment+'\')" id="btn_remove_'+detail_id+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
              <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remover</span>
            </button></td>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ')
    calculate()

  # Remove the selected serial from the order
  root.remove_row = (product_id,product_name,id,serial,comment) ->
    $("#btn_add_"+id).show()
    $("#btn_add_"+id).removeClass('hidden')
    $("#order_detail #row_"+id).remove()
    if $("tbody#order_detail").children().length == 0
      $("#order_table").hide()
      $("#process_order").hide()
      $("#update_order").hide()
      $("#empty_orden_alert").show()
    calculate()

  # Calculates subtotal, comission, tax and total
  root.calculate = (row) ->
    # Calculate comissions
    comission_percent = $("#comission_"+row).html()
    if comission_percent == ""
      $("#comission_"+row).html("0")
      comission_percent = 0
    $("#comission_"+row+'_input').val(comission_percent)
    subtotal = 0
    comission = 0
    $("#order_detail tr td a[id^=price_]").each ->
      # Sum subtotal
      i = parseFloat($(this).text());
      subtotal += i
      # Get row ID
      id = this.id
      id = id.split('_');
      id = id[1]
      p = parseFloat($("#comission_"+id).text())/100
      comission += (i*p)
    # Calculate taxes
    iva = $("#iva").val()
    tax = subtotal * iva
    # Calculate total
    total = subtotal - comission - tax
    # To display
    $("#subtotal").text(subtotal)
    $("#comission").text(comission)
    $("#tax").text(tax)
    $("#total").text(total)
    # To send as params
    $("#order_subtotal").val(subtotal)
    $("#order_comission").val(comission)
    $("#order_tax").val(tax)
    $("#order_total").val(total)

  # Disable non numbers from the keyboard
  root.just_numbers = (e) ->
    keynum = if window.event then window.event.keyCode else e.which
    if keynum == 8 or keynum == 46
      return true
    /\d/.test String.fromCharCode(keynum)
```

Any idea?

Comment: It would help if you post the actual code in those files.

Comment: Done, please check the comment above @eugen

Comment: So you're defining `root.calculate`, trying to call `calculate` (which isn't defined anywhere global), and you're getting a ReferenceError because you didn't define `calculate` anywhere in scope? Am I missing anything?

Comment: I'm not a expert using coffeescript, I'm not sure what's means root. If I call to calculate function on a Purchase view, this will execute the function on purcharse.coffee right? @muistooshort

Comment: There is no `calculate` function anywhere so you can't say `calculate()`. Looks like you do have a `root.calculate` function though.

Comment: Hey I check the source from chrome, and my javascript compiled looks like this:

  `return root.remove_row = (product_id,product_name,id,serial,comment) -&gt;
    $("#btn_add_"+id).show()
    $("#btn_add_"+id).removeClass('hidden')
    $("#order_detail #row_"+id).remove()
    if $("tbody#order_detail").children().length == 0
      $("#order_table").hide()
      $("#process_order").hide()
      $("#update_order").hide()
      $("#empty_orden_alert").show()
    calculate()` @muistooshort

Comment: So where are you expecting this `calculate` function to come from?